# Showing product brand

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For the last couple of hours I have been going over the same code over and over again. I am annoyed that it probably has a very simple fix.

Basically I am trying to show the brand of each product in a product slideshow in WP with WooCommerce Brands.

Product slideshow is working but I am just unable to access the brand name of each product.

I will just copy the code where I gather the details within the loop for products:

```
$product = get_sub_field('product_name');
$product_name = $product->post_title;
$product_link = get_post_permalink($product->ID);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID), 'full' );
$product = wc_get_product($product->ID );
```

The above is fine and allows me access to all the details apart from brand name. For brand name I have tried quite a few things including:

```
$brands = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand');
$product_brand = $brands->name;
```

$product-brand is not returning the brand name of the product in question...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this piece of code. at this site http://www.techniquewebdesign.co.uk/show-woocommerce-brand-name/

```
<?php 
    $brands = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brand', array("fields" => "all") );
    foreach( $brands as $brand ) {
        echo $brand->name; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show brand name in product details page you can use the following code in functions.php, this shows brand name before the product title.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_single_title',5);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_my_single_title' ) ) {
     function woocommerce_my_single_title() {

    global $product;
    $taxonomy = 'brand';
    $slug = 'brand'; //Or whatever the slug of "Brand" is
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, $taxonomy);
    //Gets the ID of the Parent category

       $term_id = $term->term_id;
       //Get the Child terms
       $brand_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "all") );

           foreach ($brand_terms as $brand_item) {
           // Hunt out the child term that is a child of the parent
           if ( $brand_item->parent == $term_id ) {
               //Get the name of the brand

               $brand = $brand_item->name;
               break; //Assumes you've only assigned one Brand
           }
           }
 ?>  

    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><span><?php echo $brand ?></span></h2>
<?php
   }
}
?>
```